# Having trouble calling a void method on an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to make a card game. In one class I have methods to make a hand for a player and a dealer and in the other class I am executing the game. My problem is when trying to make an arraylist for my player's hand, I can't call a void method to add cards to the List and am unsure how to do so without an error?

Answer (score 1):

addCards method is a void method. Therefore it will not return anything. But in the code you are trying to assign that to a variable. That is a compile error.
Remove that assign part.

Comment: But if i call the addCards method on simply the object from the previous class, in this case input, then how do I then fit the card into an ArrayList?

Comment: That depend on your design, what you want to do with the addCards method?

Comment: I want to generate a hand of cards for a player, like in poker. So I'm trying to give the ArrayList player 2 cards right away, and these cards will come from removing a card from a deck and sending them to the ArrayList

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand ur usecase properly. you can return the array list from the method. Then you wil able to assign that to the variable

Comment: The arrayList from which method? I know this works if I change my addCards method to return an arrayList but I'd like to keep it void, so I'm not sure what you're suggesting

Comment: If i simply do input.addCards(deck.remove(0)); it compiles and I'm sure it adds the card to input but my problem is how to get this card into the ArrayList?

Comment: What are the functions available on `CardPile`? Is there a getCard or something? The problem with the code you're showing is that I have no idea what `CardPile` is.

Answer (score 0):

deck.remove() is the void method that it's unhappy with. You are using deck.remove as if it will return something and that something will be passed to addCards.

Comment: the remove method will return something! It returns card C that is removed from the deck

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `CardPile` has a means of retrieving it's cards (via a getter method or something), then I don't see why you couldn't just do this:

```
input.addCards(deck.remove(0));
player.add(input.pop()); // or whatever the getter method for `CardPile` is
```

Comment: I get a compiler error saying I can't convert ArrayList<Card> to Card

Comment: Could you just edit your question and post all the code you're using? It's very difficult to understand what's what based on the way you have your individual code snippets laid out in the question. Just post the entire source file(s) please.